# User input error in java method being skipped over

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

My java program here is expected to take the user input in my getState() method but instead, it skips right along to the next method and throws an error as a result. I have tried many different thing and nothing seems to be working

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        try {
            System.out.println("Welcome to our survey. You may enter \"quit\" at any time to cancel the survey.");
            int age = getAge();
            String[][] states = readStateFile();
            String state = getState(states);
            int ZIPCode = getZIPCode();
            System.out.printf("\nAge:\t\t%d\n", age);
            System.out.printf("Address:\t%s %s\n\n", ZIPCode, state);
            System.out.println("Your survey is complete!");
        } catch (CancelledSurveyException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Thank you for your time.");
        }
    }

    public static int getAge() throws CancelledSurveyException {

        int age = 0;
        try {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter age: ");
            while (age < 18) {

                age = keyboard.nextInt();

                if (age < 18) {
                    System.out.println("You are too young to be taking this survey!");
                    throw new CancelledSurveyException(null);
                }

            }
            keyboard.close();

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return age;
    }

    public static String[][] readStateFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        String[][] states = new String[50][2];
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("states.bin"));
        try {
            int row = 0;
            while (true) {
                String abbreviation = dis.readUTF();
                String name = dis.readUTF();
                states[row][0] = abbreviation;
                states[row][1] = name;
                row++;
            }
        } catch (EOFException e) {
            // end of file reached
        } finally {
            dis.close();
        }
        return states;
    }

    public static String getState(String[][] states) throws CancelledSurveyException {
        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter your state abbreviation: ");
            String abbr = scanner1.nextLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
                if (states[i][0].equalsIgnoreCase(abbr)) {
                    return states[i][1];
                }
            }
            throw new CancelledSurveyException("Invalid state abbreviation.");
        } finally {
            scanner1.close();
        }
    }

    public static int getZIPCode() throws CancelledSurveyException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            while (true) {
                System.out.print("Please enter your ZIP code or 'quit' to quit: ");
                String input = scanner.nextLine().trim();
                if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
                    throw new CancelledSurveyException("Your survey was cancelled.");
                }
                try {
                    int zipCode = Integer.parseInt(input);
                    if (zipCode < 10000 || zipCode > 99999) {
                        System.out.println("Invalid ZIP code.");
                    } else {
                        return zipCode;
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input. Please enter a number.");
                }
            }
        } finally {
            scanner.close();
        }
    }
}
```

My java program here is expected to take the user input in my getState() method but instead, it skips right along to the next method and throws an error as a result. I have tried many different thing and nothing seems to be working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Comment: Welcome to our survey. You may enter "quit" at any time to cancel the survey.
Enter age: 20
Enter your state abbreviation: 
Exception in thread "main" Thank you for your time.
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
 at main.main(main.java:16)

Comment: Also you are closing system.in. Just create a single Scanner in `main` and pass it to the functions which use it. Never close System.in.